# update Activity variables when returning from shortcut intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I created a shortcut intent in my app, and the shortcut created on the homescreen successfully.
When I click the shortcut I want to be able to update one of my activity variables corresponding the shortcut name. How can I do it? How do I know If I am returning from an intent? and how I get the intent's name?
this is my add shortcut function:

```
private void addShortcut() {
        // Adding shortcut for MainActivity
        // on Home screen
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(GroupChat.this, SignUp.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, groupName);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(GroupChat.this,
                        R.drawable.contact));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        GroupChat.this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without knowing what you are actually trying to do, you can pass variables with the first intent with extras in the intent.

```
shortcutIntent.putExtra("NameOfVariable","input");
```

Since your app will launch with a parameter only from your shortcut you can tell if you have it from your intent.

```
Intent intent = context.getActivity().getIntent();
String var=intent.getStringExtra("NameOfVariable");
```

This will give you your value if you are coming from your shortcut and not when launched from your normal icon.